# Chrome does not go to localhost website but rather nginx screen

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, localhost, virtual-machine

I setup a VM Ubuntu 18.04 and using a LNMP stack. I have my website working and connecting just fine in firefox, but for chrome it just points to the "Welcome to Nginx!" Screen.

I have tried disabling caches, removing anything relating to caches, and browsing in incognito mode. All the stack overflow answerI have found didn't help, which included going to chrome flags and doing some things there.

For the life of me I cannot figure out why it works on Firefox but not Chrome. I just put my website live today and a lot of CSS is off because its chrome based and not FF based. I want to correct it, but working in a non-local environment is driving me crazy.

Below is my nginx setup.

```
server {
    server_name zeragames.localhost;
    root /var/www/html/zeragames/web; ## <-- Your only path reference.

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Block access to scripts in site files directory
    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    location @rewrite {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1; # For Drupal <= 6
        rewrite ^ /index.php; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|/(\.(?!well-known).*)|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config$|/#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        # Ensure the php file exists. Mitigates CVE-2019-11043
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
        # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
        # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        # PHP 5 socket location.
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        # PHP 7 socket location.
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
    # with a language prefix.
    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Enforce clean URLs
    # Removes index.php from urls like www.example.com/index.php/my-page --> www.example.com/my-page
    # Could be done with 301 for permanent or other redirect codes.
    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/(.*)") {
        return 307 $1$2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a similar problem. Chrome suddenly started to redirect http://localhost to https://localhost. Firefox accepts http on localhost still. I haven't found a fix yet, though.